# Illegal characters in path exception when Transforming XML

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, transformation

I am loading XML from a file, and then I want to transform it with XSLT to HTML. For that purpose I use the overload of Transform with 2 strings as parameters and therefore I make the XML into string. (The XSL is working - checked separately). But when I try to run it - I get exception at the `result` parameter of the `.Transform()` method.

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
XslCompiledTransform xsltTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();
string htmlResult = "test";
string xmlContents;

private string getXMLAsString(XmlDocument myxml)
{

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    XmlTextWriter tx = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
    myxml.WriteTo(tx);

    string str = sw.ToString();
    return str;
} 

public String getHTMLresult()
{
    xml.Load(@"L:\ProjectGroup\GK\XML documents\Parent-Child.xml");
    xmlContents = getXMLAsString(xml);
    xsltTrans.Load(@"L:\ProjectGroup\GK\XML documents\blah.xsl");
    xsltTrans.Transform(xmlContents, htmlResult); 
    return htmlResult;
}
```

Is it because `htmlResult` already has a value? But if I leave it blank, or set it to `null` I get exception `null values are not allowed`. Then how can I solve this problem with illegal characters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as short as possible version, try it:

```
XslCompiledTransform xsltTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();
string htmlResult;
string xmlContents = @"L:\ProjectGroup\GK\XML documents\Parent-Child.xml";

public String getHTMLresult()
{
    xsltTrans.Load(@"L:\ProjectGroup\GK\XML documents\blah.xsl");
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    XmlTextWriter xw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
    xsltTrans.Transform(xmlContents, null, xw);
    htmlResult = sw.ToString();
    return htmlResult;
}
```